# JQuery $.contains method always returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue here with this part of JQuery code:

```
$(".roomblock_slots li").droppable({ activeClass: "drop_here", hoverClass: "hover_here", tolerance: "pointer",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var container = $(this);
            if (container.contains(container,"div")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } });
```

I'm trying to drop an element into a li element, and I want to check if it contains a div element. The issue is, the function itself always returns false and never goes into "return false;", even if the li contains a div element, like this:

```
<li class="ui-droppable">
    <div class="ui-draggable">
</li>
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: `container.has('div')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The utility method `$.contains` does not work as you expect.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

The parameters it takes are: `container` and `contained`, and you use it like:

```
$.contains(container, contained)
```

Both parameters are supposed to be DOM elements...not jQuery objects or selectors.

So in your case, since you're not looking for a specific element being contained in another specific element, you can't use `$.contains` - you must use another method.

I would suggest using `.find` and counting how many match:

```
if (container.find("div").length > 0) {

}
```

Of course, if you only want to look at immediate children, use:

```
if (container.children("div").length > 0) {

}
```

Comment: Yes. It states the following: The $.contains() method returns true if the DOM element provided by the second argument is a descendant of the DOM element provided by the first argument.

Comment: So I'm seriously wondering why it doesn't work. Also, I tried $.find() earlier. Forgot I needed to check the length specifically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sefam I just edited, hopefully with an explanation that helps. The problem is with what arguments the `$.contains` method accepts

Comment: @lan - The `> 0` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes I know, a lot of things are "unnecessary" in Javascript because things are implicitly done, but I like to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

When chaining you'll do:

```
if ( container.has('div') ) {...}
```

Comment: You can't pass a selector as the second parameter. It only accepts DOM elements for both parameters.

Comment: @lan - Looks like you *can* pass a selector in `.has`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/j2tcL/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - the comment was on a part of the answer containing `$.contains`, which I removed as it's not really the proper method at all to use for this. `has()` would be the proper method !